# ASP.NET MVC EF Code Migration on IIS 8 Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, ef-code-first

I have an application which uses IIS Server Express. I want it to use IIS on my pc.
My application is working with IIS Server Express perfectly but when I try to host on IIS I get th following error message:
"Migrations is enabled for context 'PSTContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console."

Anybody can help me?

Comment: What is the connection string to your database?

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LASZLOURACS-PC\SQL2K14; Initial Catalog=PST; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: The IIS Express process runs under the logged in user.  I therefore think the issue is that the context of your app hasn't got access to the database.  If you update your connection string with a valid username and password, that should resolve the problem.  If you want it as pass-through you may need to update the IIS config on the app pool.